# Limit a hashed and encoded string to 44 characters: NodeJs

Tags: node.js, base64, sha256

Here is a sample input.

```
426155Grtyhr8888xxxxxxx7777BDTR56654.88555G77D6666FF555W44RT46G666D55TY_3rtyDeeeeeEEE9
```

And follow the steps given bellow.

1. add a salt to the string. My salt is: 'tttttttttt'
2. Hash this salted string using "SHA-256".
3. encode using base64

I need to out put a string 44 characters long. Here I have provide a sample code I made.

```
var str_salted = str+'tttttttttt';
var sha256 = require('sha256');
var str_myHash = sha256(str_salted);
var str_encoded = new Buffer(str_myHash).toString('base64');
console.log(str_encoded);
```

This code outputs a very long string. I need to limit this string to 44 characters. How can I do this.

Comment: Use substring `str_encoded.substring(0, 44);`

Comment: You have misunderstand my word "limit". I don't need a part from the string. But I need the entire string to be generated in 44 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Here I used `crypto` for solve this problem.

Following is my code.

```
var crepto = require('crypto');
var output = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(str_salted).digest("base64");
```

If any string hased using "sha256" and digest to base64, it provides a 44 long string.